# mysql show databases not showing databases that are in /opt/bitnami/mysql/data directory

Tags: server, mysql, aws

I have an ebs-backed ec2 ubuntu server which is running but unreachable.

There are very stupidly no recent backups.

I made a snapshot of the block, created a volume, spun up a new instance, attached the new volume. I see all the data from my site in the `/opt/bitnami/mysql/data` directory, but when I go into the `mysql` console, it shows only `information_schema` and `test` when I type `show databases;`.

How can I 'point' mysql to the correct folder?

Comment: ** There are very stupidly no recent backups ** ok just have to mention that on ec2 that is supper silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your setup its really hard to say but I see two possibilities:

- Fist check permissions, and make sure that the files and folders under mysql/data belong to mysql:mysql
- Next `cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep datadir` That's where mysql is looking for your files. You can either copy the files there or change that line in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Make sure to turn off mysql before you go messin' with the data files.

Comment: And, I can't jab enough that you should run backups on ec2. It's designed to be non-persistent storage. EBS only gives us a safety net that we shouldn't rely on. I suggest mounting your datadir in it's own ebs volume and snapshotting it with a cron. It's stupid easy to do. (admin jab over)

Comment: `ec2-create-snapshot -K $KEY -C $CERT  -d \"\`date\`\" $vol` in a cron should do the trick to create backups. -- $vol should be the volume id.

Comment: Thank you - the snapshot was done. The backups were being run, BUT NOT UPLOADED TO S3!!!!
This wasn't actually the answer - what I did was start a new instance, empty the /opt/bitnami dir and mount there.
But thanks for the tips, they did help. And the admin jab was definitely in place.